# Replacing bold (strong) and italic (em) tags with custom tags

Tags: c#, html, string, replace

I need to find a way to replace the bold (strong) and italic (em) tags in a text string with either "bold", "italic" or "bolditalic". Basically any text that is just "bold" will have the "bold" tag, any text that is just "italic" will have the "italic" tag and any text that is both "bold" and "italic" will have the "bolditalic" tag around it.

I can't do a simple replace on the text and I was thinking about using HtmlAgilityPack but I cannot work out how I would use this to achieve what I want because it needs to work out which opening tags were used to determine which closing tags are needed. Can anyone offer any suggestions? Here are some examples of how I need it to work:

This:

```
<strong><em>The quick brown fox</em> jumps over the lazy dog.</strong>
```

Needs to be:

```
<bolditalic>The quick brown fox</bolditalic><bold> jumps over the lazy dog.</bold>
```

This:

```
<em><strong>The </strong></em><strong>quick<em> brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</em></strong>
```

Needs to be:

```
<bolditalic>The </bolditalic><bold>quick</bold><bolditalic> brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</bolditalic>
```

This:

```
<strong>The quick</strong> brown <em>fox jumps over</em> the lazy dog.
```

Needs to be:

```
<bold>The quick</bold> brown <italic>fox jumps over</italic> the lazy dog.
```

**UPDATED**

I have started working on the following code using HtmlAgilityPack which I have got working for some scenarios but not for all of them. I am wondering if I am overcomplicating this or if anyone can offer me any help as to how I could improve this and get it working for all scenarios?

```
// Variables
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

// Load html document
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(text);

string test = string.Empty;

foreach (HtmlNode node in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants())
{
    // If just text (i.e. not bold or italic)
    if (node.Name == "#text" && node.ParentNode.Name != "strong" && node.ParentNode.Name != "em" && node.ParentNode.Name != "bold"
            && node.ParentNode.Name != "italic" && node.ParentNode.Name != "bolditalic")
        result.Append(node.InnerHtml);

    // If bold or italic
    if (node.Name == "strong" || node.Name == "em")
    {
        // Is bold or italic?
        bool bold = node.Name == "strong";

        // If italic/bold child node exists
        if (node.ChildNodes != null && (bold && node.ChildNodes.Any(x => x.Name == "em")) || !bold && node.ChildNodes.Any(x => x.Name == "strong"))
        {
            // Variables
            int count = 0;

            // Get em/strong sub-nodes
            var subNodes = bold ? node.ChildNodes.Where(x => x.Name == "em") : node.ChildNodes.Where(x => x.Name == "strong");

            // Loop through subNodes
            foreach (var subNode in subNodes)
            {
                // Variables
                string contentBefore = string.Empty;
                string contentAfter = string.Empty;
                count++;

                // Add "bold only" or "italic only" content before "em" or "strong" tag (if there is any)  (only do this on first instance of "em" or "strong" because this will be part the "contentAfter" method below on any other instances)
                if (count == 1 && node.InnerHtml.Substring(0, node.InnerHtml.IndexOf(subNode.OuterHtml)).Length > 0)
                {
                    // Get "bold only" or "italic only" content before "em" or "strong" tag and add to result
                    contentBefore = node.InnerHtml.Substring(0, node.InnerHtml.IndexOf(subNode.OuterHtml));
                    result.Append(string.Format("<{1}>{0}</{1}>", contentBefore, bold ? "bold" : "italic"));
                }

                // Add "bolditalic" content to result
                result.Append(string.Format("<bolditalic>{0}</bolditalic>", subNode.InnerHtml));

                // Add "bold only" or "italic only" content after "em" or "strong" tag (if there is any)
                if (node.InnerHtml.Substring(subNode.StreamPosition).Length > subNode.OuterHtml.Length)
                {
                    // Get next instance of "em" or "strong"
                    int nextInstanceOfEmOrStrong = (node.OuterHtml.Substring(subNode.StreamPosition + subNode.OuterHtml.Length).Contains(bold ? "<em>" : "<strong>")) ? node.OuterHtml.Substring(subNode.StreamPosition + subNode.OuterHtml.Length).IndexOf(bold ? "<em>" : "<strong>") : -1;

                    // Get remaining content to the next instance of an "em" or "strong" tag (if there is another instance otherwise just get the remaining content)
                    if (nextInstanceOfEmOrStrong > 0)
                        // Get content between this "em" or "strong" tag and the next "em" or "strong" tag
                        contentAfter = node.OuterHtml.Substring(subNode.StreamPosition + subNode.OuterHtml.Length, nextInstanceOfEmOrStrong);
                    else
                        // Get remaining content but remove "</strong>" or "</em>" tag from the end
                        contentAfter = node.OuterHtml.Substring(subNode.StreamPosition + subNode.OuterHtml.Length, node.OuterHtml.Substring(subNode.StreamPosition + subNode.OuterHtml.Length).Length - (bold ? 9 : 5));

                    // Add "bold only" or "italic only" content to the end of the result
                    result.Append(string.Format("<{1}>{0}</{1}>", contentAfter, bold ? "bold" : "italic"));
                }
            }
        }
        else
            result.Append(string.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", bold ? "bold" : "italic", node.InnerHtml));
    }
}

// Return results
return result.ToString();
```

Comment: but... but... `bolditalic` isn't valid markup

Comment: You need to use an HTML parser and then recompose your HTML or XML from scratch.

Comment: (<[a-zA-Z]*>) use this type of regex and loop through each group then replace. It is just a hint. u can complete with help of it if you want complete answer then you have to wait for tomorrow . 
I can post tomorrow only

Comment: @madan Regular expressions aren't a good choice for parsing HTML, really. HTML isn't a regular language.

Comment: ok then find other option

Comment: There is a library available for htmltoxaml you can try

Comment: I know "bolditalic" isn't valid mark-up, this is for use in an XML export that will be imported into InDesign. I didn't mention that because I didn't feel it was important.

Comment: What about `<strong>The <em>quick</em> brown fox</strong>`? Should it be `<bold>The</bold><bolditalic>quick</bolditalic><bold>brown fox</bold>`, or `<bold>The<italic>quick</italic> brown fox</bold>`?

Comment: It should be <bold>The</bold><bolditalic>quick</bolditalic><bold>brown fox</bold>. Basically what I am importing this content into doesn't understand that something is bold and italic because it has bold and italic tags around it, it needs to know which parts of the text are bold and italic.